# diff gives a variable as 8 x 0

Tags: r, tidyverse

Need to difference 2nd column in Sample_data. Code used in R as follows:

```
y<-Sample_Data[,2]
> d.y<-diff(y, lag=1)
> diff(y)
# A tibble: 8 x 0
```

Why do I get `d.y` as a variable 8 x 0?

Sample_data:

```
Day        Amount
01-01-2017  1400
02-01-2017  1500
03-01-2017  1200
04-01-2017  1300
05-01-2017  800
06-01-2017  900
07-01-2017  500
08-01-2017  1400
```

Comment: @ChristophWolk many thanks. I realized the error in my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

`y` is a tibble, but diff expects a vector. Subsetting a tibble will keep it a tibble. You can use `pull` or `$` to access the data as a vector:

```
library(dplyr)
y <- pull(Sample_Data, 2)
diff(y)
```

Comment: Or perhaps `diff(Sample_Data$Amount)`.

Comment: I suspect some of the confusion come from the fact that `Sample_Data[,2]` returns a vector when `Sample_Data` is a data frame.  The `[` extractor has a different behavior with tibble objects. So understanding the class of the object is important (and not readily apparent from the sample data given).

Comment: and if you really want to use `pull` instead of `[[` you should put `library(dplyr)` before your code.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper: Good point, and I've added it to be explicit. Given that the question contains tibbles and is tagged tidyverse, I asuumed that was a given, but OP could have just loaded `tibble`.

Answer (score 1):

This what you want? A quick example.

```
day <- as.POSIXct(c("01-01-2017", "02-01-2017", "03-01-2017", "04-01-2017",
                    "05-01-2017", "06-01-2017", "07-01-2017", "08-01-2017"),
                  format = "%m-%d-%Y")
amount <- c(1400, 1500, 1200, 1300, 800, 900, 500, 1400)
df <- data.frame(Day = day, Amount = amount)
df <- cbind(df, c(0, Diff = diff(df$Amount, lag = 1)))
print(df)
```